# Find the matrix representing the relations S o R, where the matrices representing R and S.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, relations

I am having difficulty understanding the following:

Find the matrix representing the relations $S\circ R$, where the matrices representing $R$ and $S$:

$$M_R = \begin{bmatrix}1 \ 0 \ 1 \\ 1 \ 1 \ 0 \\ 0 \ 0 \ 0\end{bmatrix} \text{ and }M_C = \begin{bmatrix}0 \ 1 \ 0 \\ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \\ 1 \ 0 \ 1\end{bmatrix} \implies M_R \odot M_S \implies \begin{bmatrix}1 \ 1 \ 1 \\ 0 \ 1 \ 1 \\ 0 \ 0 \ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

I know that if the composite matrix has $t_{ij} = 1$ if and only if $r_{ik} = s_{kj} = 1$ for some $k$. I am unsure how to arrive at the answer to the right.

Comment: Do you know how to multiply two matrices?

Comment: Oh wow... The explanation in the book is not the forward with it. Thanks, that clears my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using standard [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication),

$$\pmatrix{1&0&1\\1&1&0\\0&0&0}\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&1}=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&0}.$$